# Editing PASCAL VOC bounding box data

Tags: windows, tensorflow, neural-network, computer-vision

I'm generating data for training an object detection ANN. I'm currently automatically generating the training data based of rules which i'm implementing (automatically captures the image and creates bounding boxes), however the algorithm for creating the data is imprecise (otherwise i wouldnt need an AI for it)

I am looking for an app or github repo that inputs the Pascal VoC annotation file and image, and allows you to visually modify (add/remove/update) the bounding boxes to clean up the data. Using windows currently.

Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on platform I use:

Linux/win - [LabelImg](https://github.com/tzutalin/labelImg)

macOS - [RectLabel](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/rectlabel-for-object-detection/id1210181730?mt=12) (unfortunately not open source, but only costs $0.99)

Comment: im using windows, but labelimg seems to have a windows build, i'll let you know how it goes